# What's the expected label file format for Lightning Web Runtime OSS?

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, lwc-oss, lwr, lwr-oss

In the Lightning Web Runtime OSS documentation, in the ["Use Module Providers" section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-packages-modules.html?&_ga=2.188592424.129249412.1663015224-1781581446.1663015224#use-module-providers), I can see "Your application components can now statically import labels sourced from JSON files in your project’s $rootDir/src/labels directory".

What is the expected JSON file format ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some tests, it looks like the following is working:
In the src/labels directory, create one JSON file per locale you want to support, for instance `fr.json`, `en_US.json` etc

In each file, format should be like this:

```
{
    "c.greeting": "Hello World",
    "c.greeting2": "Hello Again"
}
```

Then you can import your label in your LWC OSS like on the Platform which is pretty cool for reusability:

```
import GREETING from '@salesforce/label/c.greeting';
```

Looks like the correct locale is used if the related file exists, otherwise english is used. As soon as a file exists, all labels must be in there (it won't default to english for a specific value, just for a whole file).

This is just what I discovered by testing though and as it's not officially documented it could break at any time. I tried to get some more official information on the related [Trailblazer Community Group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000JdVQpSAN).